# Can we try not using Apple In-App purchase in country like Vietnam?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment

We are working on a game app on iOS. Our target users are in Asia which have limited credit card access thus that make it difficult to use In-App Purchase API. Can we implement another way of payment instead, or just instruct users to pay somewhere else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple does not allow this. In the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) under **section 11 Purchasing and currencies** it states clearly -

> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Anyway what if we implement the IAP along with instruction that user can also pay on our website ? Is that possible ?

Comment: @Phally You say thanks for the answer but then you completely ignore it by asking your question all over again. Apple won't allow you to offer an alternative payment method unless it is for real-world goods.